# "syntax error unexpected token fi" when trying to run bash script

Tags: scripts

I tried to run a script, but I get this error. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

```
# Make the mesh using blockMesh (serial) and decompose it.
if [ $runNumber -eq 1 ]
   cp constant/polyMesh/blockMeshDict ./
   rm -rf constant/polyMesh/*
   mv ./blockMeshDict constant/polyMesh
   blockMesh > log.blockMesh 2>&1
   decomposePar -cellDist -force > log.decomposePar 2>&1
fi
```

and this is my error:

```
./Allrun: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./Allrun: line 31: `fi'
```

Comment: 10.04 has reached end of life. Please upgrade to 12.04 LTS (supported until April 2017), 14.04 LTS (supported until April 2019) or 15.10 (supported only until July 2016).

Comment: I'm using an special open source code named OpenFOAM, and the version I use just work with the 10.04 . i have to use this ubuntu

Comment: No, you have to change the code you're working with. That's like if you continued to use a software that only works on Windows 98.

Comment: it's a little complicated. I'm using SOWFA code, a code for cfd simulations.it works with OpenFOAM 2.0.x and this OF works in ubuntu10.04

Comment: Did you try that it's not compatible with later versions of OpenFOAM?

Comment: guys, yeah he's using 10.04, but this Q has nothing to do with 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

You must add **then** after square brackets because then IF will know that IF $runNumber -eq 1 he will do that.

So correct script should look like:

```
if [ $runNumber -eq 1 ]; then
   cp constant/polyMesh/blockMeshDict ./
   rm -rf constant/polyMesh/*
   mv ./blockMeshDict constant/polyMesh
   blockMesh > log.blockMesh 2>&1
   decomposePar -cellDist -force > log.decomposePar 2>&1
fi
```

Some examples for future: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/

Comment: another question : what is the command that I should use to compile this script?

Comment: @Mohsen It's a Bash script, you don't compile it, you just run it. `bash /PATH/TO/SCRIPT`. Or if the first line of the script is `#! /bin/bash` and it was made executable (using `chmod +x /PATH/TO/SCRIPT`), you can run it directly.

Comment: Without space `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Gen That doesn't matter. `#! /bin/bash` and `#!/bin/bash` both work, but the one with space is more readable in my opinion.

Comment: @Mohsen Please don't add new information (especially command outputs, just look at the horrible formatting!) in comments. Edit your question instead. Also, only those reading all answers and all of their comments will find your information here, and if the answer got removed or for any other reason, your comment would vanish silently with nobody noticing. So please edit your question and we can look after the new problem.

Comment: Oh, but `no such file or directory` is a pretty clear error message in my opinion. The file names you specified in your script simply do not exist, or as you're using relative paths, you're executing the script from the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement in bash looks like this (indentation is optional):

```bsh
if [ CONDITION ]
  then COMMAND1
       MORE_COMMANDS
  else COMMAND2
       MORE_COMMANDS
fi
```

Or in one line:

```bsh
if [ CONDITION ] ; then COMMAND1 ; MORE_COMMANDS ; else COMMAND2 ; MORE_COMMANDS ; fi
```

It is important that `if` and `then` are two separate commands (separate lines or separated by `;`), but that `then` or `else` and the first command of the following code block must be one single command (in the same line and not separated).

So your code example has to look like this:

```bsh
# Make the mesh using blockMesh (serial) and decompose it.
if [ $runNumber -eq 1 ]
   then cp constant/polyMesh/blockMeshDict ./
        rm -rf constant/polyMesh/*
        mv ./blockMeshDict constant/polyMesh
        blockMesh > log.blockMesh 2>&1
        decomposePar -cellDist -force > log.decomposePar 2>&1
fi
```